# how to add a template within the checkout/cart/item/default.phtml (simple)

Tags: magento, templates

I want to add a custom phtml under the product name in the checkout_cart_index, i found that in checkout.xml, there is a

simplecheckout/cart_item_renderercheckout/cart/item/default.phtml

what i want is, i want to add a block with template (phtml), so that i can use getchildhtml('xxx') to call the template, which show a text under the product name. Since this phtml is used in other place, that's why i want this approach to make the phtml reusable, any suggestion?, i am using CE1.9
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better you can copy and paste the below code in default.phtml after product name

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('blocktype')->setTemplate('temlate path')->tohtml(); ?>
```

block type - your block type

templatepath - your phtml file path